# How do incrementers work in CMD For Loops?

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to create a for loop that cycles through the PNGs in a directory and uses ImageMagick to combine them into pairs.

This is what I have, but **++A** is not accepted by Windows CMD:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /b /od *.png')  do  magick "%A" "%(++A)" +append output-"%A".png
```

Basically, what I want to happen is this:

```
array = filenames;

for(f=0; array[f]; f++) // cycle through my files
   magick array[f] array[++f]; // magick file1 file2... magick file3 file4...
```

Bonus Points if this can be done in one line.

Extra bonus points if you can tell me how to convert %A into its iteration number.

For instance, if %A is pointed at the third filename in the array, how can I make it output "3" (or "2" if the count starts at 0).

Disclaimer: These bonus points are all theoretical as I am a "New Contributor" and hence cannot vote yet.

Comment: Do you insist on using BATCH/CMD for this? I believe you'd find it much easier in PowerShell...

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin - It doesn't matter too much for me. Whichever leads to an efficient and comprehendible answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't. %A is just a read-only string variable that is only updated between 'for' iterations – you cannot "increment" it. Even if it were an array index, Cmd doesn't have preincrement or any other inline expressions (except for string substitution) and it doesn't even have arrays.

You could emulate an array using "delayed expansion", by creating variables named like `%foo1%`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=0
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /od *.png') do (
    set file!i!=%%A
    set /a i=i+1
)
set /a n=%i%-2
for /l %%A in (0,2,%n%) do call :ugh %%A
goto :EOF

:ugh
:: A subroutine is needed to allow two levels of indirection, as otherwise
:: the %a% and %b% would be expanded when the 'for' line is *read* and not
:: during every iteration.
set /a a=%1
set /a b=%1+1
echo XXX: magick !file%a%! !file%b%! +append output-!file%b%!
goto :EOF
```

However, a much easier way to do this is to remember the previous file instead of the next one:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set prev=
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /od *.png') do (
    if not "!prev!"=="" echo XXX: magick !prev! %%A +append output-%%A
    if not "!prev!"=="" (set prev=) else (set prev=%%A)
)
```

But if you want oneliners, you should use PowerShell:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem *.png | Sort-Object LastWriteTime
for ($i = 0; $i+1 -lt $files.Count; $i+=2) {
    magick $files[$i] $files[$i+1] +append "output-$(files[$i])"
}
```

```
gci *.png | sort-object LastWriteTime | % {
    if ($prev) { magick "$prev" "$_" +append "output-$_"; $prev = $null; }
    else { $prev = $_ }
}
```

<sup>(Here `gci` and `%` are default aliases for `Get-ChildItem` and `ForEach-Item`.)</sup>

Comment: I think that you want `for ($i = 0; $i+1 -lt $files.Count; $i+=2) {`; with the single increment, you end up combining files 1 and 2, then 2 and 3, etc., where what is wanted is 1 and 2 then 3 and 4 etc.

Comment: Good point, fixed.

Comment: Hey! I can upvote now! Thank you, @user1686. So in short: `$files = dir *.png | Sort LastWriteTime | Select -ExpandProperty Name; for ($i = 0; $files[$i]; $i+=2) {magick $files[$i] $files[$i+1] +append "output-$($files[$i])"}`